# Scheduling tasks on 2 parallel machines

Tags: graph, scheduling, directed-acyclic-graphs

Given a DAG what's the best way to find which order to run functions on 2 parallel machines?

Each machine can run 1 task at a time and a task can't be run until its dependencies have finished executing. I know how to do it for n tasks and n machines but a bit lost for 2 machines. Any help where to begin?

Answer (score 1):

You could use CP techniques and a CP Solver.
Here is an example using CP-Optimizer in Python:

```py
# 1. PROBLEM DATA (EXAMPLE)
n        = 20
DURATION = [ 108, 90, 67, 286, 107, 65, 468, 444, 126, 50, 143, 450, 275, 125, 143, 215, 85, 45, 204, 488 ]
DAG      = [ [0,5], [1,6], [2,4], [3,7], [3,8], [4,10], [5,9], [6,11], [7,13], [8,12],[9,14], [10,15], [12,16], [14,17], [15,18], [16,19] ]
N        = range(n)

# 2. MODELING THE PROBLEM WITH CP-OPTIMIZER
from docplex.cp.model import *
m = CpoModel()
task = [interval_var(size=DURATION[i]) for i in N ]         # Decision     variables: tasks
usedMachines = sum([pulse(task[i],1) for i in N])           # Cumul function: number of tasks executing over time
m.add(minimize(max(end_of(task[i]) for i in N)))            # Objective: minimize schedule makespan
m.add([end_before_start(task[i],task[j]) for [i,j] in DAG]) # Constraints: precedence between tasks
m.add(usedMachines <= 2)                                    # Constraints: maximal number of machines

# 3. SOLVING THE PROBLEM
sol = model.solve()

# 4. DISPLAY SOLUTION
import docplex.cp.utils_visu as visu
for i in range(n):
    visu.interval(sol.get_var_solution(task[i]), i, str(i))
visu.show()
```

Example of an optimal solution to this small problem instance with optimal makespan 1992 (solve time is less than 0.01s including optimality proof):

[image]

Comment: Hi Philippe, I was able to do it in Java using a top sort on the DAG followed by sorting the values in ascending order. Then I just used if statements to assign tasks to machines while checking for dependencies. Thanks anyways, maybe it will help someone else.

Comment: Note that your approach does not guarantee to find an optimal solution (assuming you want to minimize the end time of the schedule) while the CP solver does. This scheduling problem with precedence constraints on 2 machines is NP-Complete.

Comment: You are correct, the minimum time is not found but it is minimized greatly compared to 1 machine, which was what I needed.